# Instabug 3 Android Builder crash (NullPointerException)

Tags: android, instabug

I recently updated my production Android app from Instabug 2.5.1 to 3.1.1. Since then, I have been getting consistent crash reports on Fabric caused by a NullPointerException in InstabugFeaturesManager for phones ranging from Android 4-6. I haven't seen this issue in testing or been able to reproduce it.

Here is the crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.myapp.main.MyApplication: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6032)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
   at com.instabug.library.h.a(InstabugFeaturesManager.java:70)
   at com.instabug.library.g.b(InstabugDelegate.java:208)
   at com.instabug.library.Instabug$Builder.build(Instabug.java:1277)
   at com.instabug.library.Instabug$Builder.build(Instabug.java:1372)
   at com.myapp.main.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:107)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6029)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

`build.gradle`:

```
compile('com.instabug.library:instabug:3.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support';
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms';
}
```

Note: I'm excluding those libraries because I want to control what version my app is using.

`MyApplication#onCreate()`:

```
new Instabug.Builder(this, MyConstants.Application.INSTABUG_KEY)
            .setInvocationEvent(InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE)
            .setShakingThreshold(500)
            .setCrashReportingState(Feature.State.DISABLED)
            .setTrackingUserStepsState(Feature.State.ENABLED)
            .setInAppMessagingState(Feature.State.DISABLED)
            .setIntroMessageEnabled(false)
            .setEmailFieldRequired(true)
            .build();  //Crash originates here
```

---

I would argue this is not your normal `NullPointerException` question. For one, I'm not adding anything to the build that could possibly be null and it crashing internally. Additionally, the Instabug library is heavily obfuscated so I can't make sense of why it is crashing internally. I've looked around everywhere, but haven't found a case of anyone else having this issue. Am I missing something here?

Comment: what happens if you include the library?

Comment: Did you add you app class i.e. **MyApplication** in manifest?

Comment: Yes I have. Take note, this in an app that has been in production for over a year and it was working well before the update.

Comment: Can you post the whole `MyApplication.onCreate` method, and make a [mcve]?

Comment: @jacob looks like a null Boolean was casted to boolean producing this , check for any null values in Boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to a new release (3.1.4) the Instabug team pushed out fixing this issue.